# how to target just one dropdown menu instead of all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a react project where I have 3 dropdown menus side by side and upon clicking one they all will toggle instead of just one. I tried to use a dropdown component but I'm not sure I can get it working correctly with my code. Can you show me how to fix this? I have my code uploaded to code sandbox here [link to code](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/rachelharu/react-blogr-landingpage/draft/gifted-mccarthy?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavbar.jsx) due note that it will not display on mobile screens yet so you will need to look at it in the full desktop version of the site.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {
  iconHamburger,
  iconClose,
  iconArrowDark,
  iconArrowLight,
  logo,
} from '../assets';
import { navLinks } from '../constants';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className='w-full flex py-6 ml-10 justify-between items-center navbar'>
      <img src={logo} alt='blogr' className='w-[75px] h-[30px]' />

      <ul className='list-none sm:flex hidden ml-10 justify-start items-center flex-1'>

        {navLinks.map((nav, index) => (
          <li
            key={nav.id}
            className={`font-overpass
            font-normal
            text-[12px] ${index === navLinks.length - 1 ? 'mr-0' : 'mr-10'}
          text-white`}>
            <a
              className='float-left'
              onClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
              href={`#${nav.id}`}>
              {nav.title}
              <img
                className='ml-2 mt-1 cursor-pointer float-right w-[9px] h-[6px]'
                src={iconArrowLight}
              />
            </a>

            <div className={`${toggle ? 'hidden' : 'relative'} mr-10`}>
              <ul className='list-none mt-10 absolute'>
                {nav.links.map((link, index) => (
                  <li
                    key={link.name}
                    className={`font-overpass text-black cursor-pointer ${
                      index !== nav.links.length - 1 ? 'mb-4' : 'mb-0'}`}>
                    {link.name}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>              
          

        ))}
      </ul>

      
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

navlinks

```
import { iconArrowLight } from "../assets"

export const navLinks = [
    {
        id: 'product',
        title: 'Product',
        img: iconArrowLight,
        links: [
            {
                name: 'Overview'
            },
            {
                name: 'Pricing'
            },
            {
                name: 'Marketplace'
            },
            {
                name: 'Features'
            },
            {
                name: 'Integrations'
            },
        ],
    },
    {   
        id: 'company',
        title: 'Company',
        img: iconArrowLight,
        links: [
            {
                name: 'About'
            },
            {
                name: 'Team'
            },
            {
                name: 'Blog'
            },
            {
                name: 'Career'
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 'connect',
        title: 'Connect',
        img: iconArrowLight,
        links: [
            {
                name: 'Contact'
            },
            {
                name: 'Newsletter'
            },
            {
                name: 'LinkedIn'
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the drop list is sharing one `toggle` state, therefore they open and close at same time.

You could make each drop list a separate component `DropList`, each will have an individual state of `toggle`.

It will allow adding more `DropList` easier, also keeping the code in `Navbar` cleaner.

Full example: (live modified project: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/john-zhuangzhuang-li/react-blogr-landingpage/draft/blissful-leftpad?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FNavbar.jsx&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A1%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A70%2C%22startColumn%22%3A1%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A1%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522clar2a31l000wl4hgg3wc6c6o%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%252C%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FNavbar.jsx%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clar2cuc2003q2a69w9q6oblp%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2523connect%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clar2cuc2003p2a694z3h1kvc%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D))

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  iconHamburger,
  iconClose,
  iconArrowDark,
  iconArrowLight,
  logo,
} from "../assets";
import { navLinks } from "../constants";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex py-6 ml-10 justify-between items-center navbar">
      <img src={logo} alt="blogr" className="w-[75px] h-[30px]" />

      <ul className="list-none sm:flex hidden ml-10 justify-start items-center flex-1">
        {navLinks.map((nav, index, arr) => (
          <DropList
            key={nav.id}
            mr={index === arr.length - 1 ? "mr-0" : "mr-10"}
            {...nav}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;

export const DropList = ({ id, title, links, mr }) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li
      className={`font-overpass
            font-normal
            text-[12px] ${mr}
          text-white`}
    >
      <a
        className="float-left"
        onClick={() => setToggle((prev) => !prev)}
        href={`#${id}`}
      >
        {title}
        <img
          className="ml-2 mt-1 cursor-pointer float-right w-[9px] h-[6px]"
          src={iconArrowLight}
        />
      </a>

      <div className={`${toggle ? "hidden" : "relative"} mr-10`}>
        <ul className="list-none mt-10 absolute">
          {links.map((link, index, arr) => (
            <li
              key={link.name}
              className={`font-overpass text-black  ${
                index !== arr.length - 1 ? "mb-4" : "mb-0"
              }`}
            >
              {link.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the same state to toggle all drop downs. Normally I would recommend to  create a new component for the drop down to keep the state. However since you specified that you only want one open at any time, I would recommend to change the state to keep the id of the open nav item.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { iconArrowLight, logo } from "../assets";
import { navLinks } from "../constants";

const Navbar = () => {
  const [openId, setOpenId] = useState(undefined);

  return (
    <nav className="w-full flex py-6 ml-10 justify-between items-center navbar">
      <img src={logo} alt="blogr" className="w-[75px] h-[30px]" />

      <ul className="list-none sm:flex hidden ml-10 justify-start items-center flex-1">
        {navLinks.map((nav, index) => (
          <li
            key={nav.id}
            className={`font-overpass
            font-normal
            text-[12px] ${index === navLinks.length - 1 ? "mr-0" : "mr-10"}
          text-white`}
          >
            <a
              className="float-left"
              onClick={() =>
                setOpenId((prev) => (prev === nav.id ? undefined : nav.id)) // If the id is the same as the previous id, close it
              }
              href={`#${nav.id}`}
            >
              {nav.title}
              <img
                className="ml-2 mt-1 cursor-pointer float-right w-[9px] h-[6px]"
                src={iconArrowLight}
              />
            </a>

            <div
              className={`${openId !== nav.id ? "hidden" : "relative"} mr-10`}
            >
              <ul className="list-none mt-10 absolute">
                {nav.links.map((link, index) => (
                  <li
                    key={link.name}
                    className={`font-overpass text-black cursor-pointer ${
                      index !== nav.links.length - 1 ? "mb-4" : "mb-0"
                    }`}
                  >
                    {link.name}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```